# Laravel 5 Routing Calling Wrong View

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I've got a simple Laravel 5 site that I am working on (learning Laravel)

I have a link on my 'users' view to add a 'new user':

```
<a href="{{ url('/user/create') }}">Create New User</a>
```

My user Routes look like the following:

```
Route::get('/users', 'UserController@index');
Route::get('/user/{id}', 'UserController@edit');
Route::get('/user/create', 'UserController@create');
Route::get('/user/update', 'UserController@update');
Route::get('/user/delete/{id}', 'UserController@delete');
```

My UsersController has the following:

```
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function index()
{
    $users = user::all();
    return view('user.index',compact('users'));
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function create()
{
    $userroles = userrole::all();
    return view('user.create', compact('userroles'));
}
```

When I click the link - I get the following error:

```
Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\resources\views\user\edit.blade.php)
```

I cannot figure out why it is trying to load edit.blade.php

I have tried just putting the following in my create view and it still doesn't render.

```
@extends('app')

@section('content')
Test
@endsection
```

I'm not sure why the routing is being so bizarre.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the create (and update) route before the edit route in your routes file. Laravel 1st stumbles on the edit route and treats the `create` as id.

You can test it by doing a `dd($id)` in your edit method in the controller.